# Issues with mesh deformation

Tags: armature

I have a low poly model that I am trying to rig correctly but even with editing vertex groups and weight painting I am still getting issues when moving around the bones.

Heres the blend file:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36971

I undid all my edits to the vertex groups and weight painting so all that has been done is the parenting of the mesh to the armature with automatic weights. Pretty much, Id appreciate if you could figure out whats up with the vertex groups and why they are acting so weird. thanx

Comment: You may want to double check your vertex groups. It looks like they aren't assigned properly. For example, when I tried to select the vertices in the 'abdomen' group, it selected vertices on both elbows and one wrist. Then I tried the next one in the list, 'chest', which selected the head and one vertex on the top of the left shoulder. I clicked on a couple more and everything seemed random. I think you need to reassign your vertex groups.

Comment: yeah i already tried that and even after removing certain vertices from the vertex groups it still deformed those vertices

Comment: It's your vertex groups. The first time I tried posing the left shoulder, half of the upper body stayed glued to the arm.  I fixed the chest and left shoulder by fixing the abdomen, chest, left upper arm, and left lower arm groups. After that the shoulder rotated just fine. Just make sure you're removing unwanted vertices from the groups as well as assigning the correct ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a before and after picture to illustrate what I mean. On the left is what happened when I tried rotating the left shoulder using the original vertex groups. On the right is what happened after I reassigned the vertices in the the following groups: abdomen, chest, left shoulder, left upper arm, left lower arm. Double check that you are not only assigning the vertices that you want in each group, but also removing the ones you don't want.

[image: Before and after fixing the vertex groups]

Comment: yeah I think i managed to fix the arms on my own but I was experiencing issues with the fingers

Comment: If you're having problems with the fingers, you should include that information in the original question. You have dozens of vertex groups so being more specific is really helpful for someone trying to help troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: yeah my bad, i kinda realized that as I posted that comment...srry. Im gonna try fixing it on my own again and if I cant get anything to work Ill come back here.

Comment: ah I figured it out, the abdomen and chest vertex groups were screwin everything up. man, I cant stand blender's automatic weight assigning.

Comment: I'm pretty confused by the weight assigning myself. I initially worked on the vertex groups in Edit mode by first selecting existing vertices for a group, removing them, then manually selecting new vertices and assigning them. This worked as I expected. However, when I tried doing the same thing in Weight Paint mode, the vertices that I painted didn't match the vertex groups when displayed in Edit mode. Although I'm pretty new to rigging in Blender, I thought this was odd and worth mentioning.